# How can I include a tag in html table Column?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert a anchor tag inside a column Using JavaScript or JQuery
 For example change the first column value 'A' is a link Using JavaScript or JQuery

```
<table>   
  <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>            
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>            
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>            
  </tr>    
</table>
```

I tried with this code but not working

```
var cell = document.createElement("a");
innercell .setAttribute("href","#");                     
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[1].cells[0].appendChild(innercell );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to `window.onload` event

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; //change the index in actual page
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('href',"link.html"); // replace "link.html" with your own link
a.innerHTML = "link text";
td.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using anchors normally is simply, Due to the end result not being described well give this ago.

Where you want to anchor to type

```
<a id="ANCHOR_NAME">Some Random Thing</a>
```

Where you want the link to the anchor to be just type

```
<a href="#ANCHOR_NAME">Visit the Anchor</a>
```

You can link to an anchor on another page using `href="page.html#anchor"`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to insert a anchor tag inside a column Using JavaScript or JQuery
 For example change the first column value 'A' is a link Using JavaScript or JQuery

```
<table>   
  <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>            
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="first">A</td>
    <td>B</td>            
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>            
  </tr>    
</table>
```

jQuery Example:

```
$("#first").text('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
```

EDIT: As you don't want to use an Id,

```
$("td").first().text('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
```

Comment: Thanks It is Working but i don't want to insert a id

Comment: Edited the answer without using Id. This is the easiest way in jquery rather than multiple lines.